# Как сделать последовательное исполнение setTimeout?

Tags: javascript

Меня интересует такая структура:

> привет {ожидание 5 сек}<br> как дела?
> {ожидание 20 сек}<br> чего не отвечаешь?
> {ожидание 25 сек}<br> ну не хочешь
> говорить - пока

то есть нужно с разной задержкой в линейном js коде отправлять данные на страницу.
Подскажите, как это реализовать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/RZs5Z/ — пример

```
var msgQueue = function (queue, callback){
    var msg = queue.shift();

    callback(msg.text);

    if( queue.length ){
        setTimeout(function (){
            msgQueue(queue, callback);
        }, msg.delay * 1000);
    }
};

// Пример использования
msgQueue([
      { text: 'привет', delay: 5 } // delay — в секундах
    , { text: 'как дела?', delay: 20 }
    , { text: 'чего не отвечаешь?', delay: 25 }
    , { text: 'у не хочешь говорить — пока' }
], function (text){
   // тут ваша логика для вывода сообшения
   console.log(text);
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RZs5Z/1/ — пример с возможностью "выхода" из "диалога"

Answer (score 1):

```
var timeouts = [0,5,20,25], 
chat_messages = ["привет","как дела?","чего не отвечаешь?","Не хочешь говорить - пока!"];

function send_chat_message(n){
  print_function(chat_messages[n]);//Это любая функция, типа $("body").append() или document.write
if(timeouts[n+1]!=undefined){
  if(timeouts[n+1]==0){
    send_chat_message(++n);//вызываем сразу
  }else{
    setTimeout(function(){send_chat_message(++n)},timeouts[n+1]);//вызываем через время
  }
}
}

send_chat_message(0);
```

Кстати. Не забываем про clearTimeout, если вам все-таки ответили :)